# Are "caw" or "squawk" countable nouns?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

So both "caw" and "squawk" are "a harsh noise made by a bird".

Are these two words countable or uncountable?

For example, which of the following two is more correct?

```
All night I heard the caw of the condors.
```

or

```
All night I heard the caws of the condors.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer, but an additional question: do condors caw? I think of ravens and the likes that caw...

Comment: Not sure that caw is a noun.  I'd rather say the sound of, er, condors cawing.  Squawk, on the other hand is a noun I use.  So, 'all night I heard the squawks of the macaws' works for me (although, actually, even then I reckon I'd use 'the sound of squawking macaws')

Comment: @Dan - Individual utterances by these birds are *caws* or *squawks*. A more-or-less constant flow of such sounds is *cawing* or *squawking*. All are nouns; the latter two are also present participles or gerunds.

Comment: Thanks @ErikKowal.  So 'caws' is fine (if unfamiliar - I reckon I'd rather say 'the cawing of ...').  As to the use of singular and plural forms, it puts me in mind of accounts of safaris where people see 'lion' and 'elephant' (ie singular even though meaning several animals).

Answer (score 2):

If condors sound anything like turkey vultures (and I suspect that they do), you'd do better with

> All night I heard the grunting and snuffling of the condors.

(When they roost, turkey vultures sound a lot like foraging bears.) Or you might say

> All night I heard the croaking and rattling of the ravens.

or

> All night I heard the cawing of the crows.

But those options notwithstanding, both

> All night I heard the caw of the crows.

and

> All night I heard the caws of the crows.

are not wrong, and in fact can be quite evocative in the right setting. So you have your choice of *cawing*, *caw*, or *caws* to use with any bird that makes those sounds.